# What design pattern(s) to use to encapsulate a collection of functionalities

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Suppose there is a collection of commands that needs to be implemented. A command may need some input arguments and after execution, it may return some results. A few design considerations are:

- Commands are created at run time
- Commands creation is based on user input
- Command inputs may be encrypted or compressed or both
- Different commands may need to be created in ways specific for each command
- Different commands may have different number of inputs and input types
- Command inputs are provided at runtime
- Result of different commands may have different types

For example, a command may be 'GetFileList' that receives a path to list its files and returns a list of files as a result. In this case, the command has a single input of type `string` and returns a result of type `string[]`. On the other hand, a command 'RenameFile' may have two inputs of type `string` and return a `boolean` value to indicate success or failure.

For object creation, I can think of the *Factory* and *Strategy* patterns but I cannot think of a good way to encapsulate results and input parameters. What design patterns can be useful for implementing this scenario?

Comment: I don't know about patterns.  I would guess generics would be the way to go, depending on your language.  (You don't tag your question.)  Patterns aren't the solution to every problem.  Don't fall into the Small Boy With A Pattern trap.

Comment: @duffymo I edited the question and added the tag for the language. Thanks for your advice. I am not a pro in Design Patterns but I am curious to learn and whenever I face a problem, I tend to spend some time to find out if there is any well-known pattern that can solve it or not.

Comment: Java has interfaces for a more functional style that leverage generics.  They are intended to fit into lambdas.  I would guess that C# already has such a thing, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a...

COMMAND PATTERN :)

Shortly speaking, you have to have a interface **ICommand** that has a method **execute**.

Execute method may be void or may return some result (probably in generic way). If it's void, then you have to have another generic method like **GetResult**.

When you create a method, you can pass arguments in its constructor.

Comment: Thanks for 'you can pass arguments in its constructor'. It has been bugging me for quite a while.

Answer (score 1):

Here http://www.dofactory.com/net/command-design-pattern is page where is the Command Design Pattern explained with examples.